# Не работет .click() при прогоне автотестов selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, pytest

У меня есть определенный ран с авторизацией:

```
    def login_account(self, valid_user):
        self.click_button_account()
        self.click_on_button_u_menya_est_parol()
        self.enter_email(valid_user.email)
        self.enter_password(valid_user.password)
        self.click_btn_enter()
        time.sleep(60)
        assert self.element_is_visible(self.account_locators.HEAD_YOU_LIKE_ROBOT).text == "Похоже, что Вы робот!" or self.element_is_visible(self.account_locators.HEAD_NAME_OF_USER).text == "Персонаж"
```

Но вот строка self.click_btn_enter(), ниже привожу метод данной строки

```
    def click_btn_enter(self):
        self.element_is_visible(self.account_locators.BTN_VHOD).click()
```

не хочет работать стабильно

КАК ЭТО ПРОЯВЛЯЕТСЯ

первый раз метод отрабатывает корреткно - кнопка нажимается
Но если запустить автотест повторно, то кнопка не нажмется и после ввода почты и пароля в поля ничего не произойдет

НО! при этом если в код добавить еще одну строку с кликом, то прогон автотеста опять отработает корректно и кнопка кликнется

НО! что бы он отработал еще раз корректно, придется добавить еще одну строку с кликом

короче очень странно, если можете - помогите

UPD
Если убрать проверку(assert) на результаты клика по кнопке(фразы которые должны быть на странице после) то тест проходит, то есть клик все таки происходит, но почему тогда не реагирует кнопка?

Вот текст ошибки который появляется если assert есть - https://gist.github.com/sergeycd/a42bd5e54a1aeab221510850819128af
А на скрине если убрать assert

[image: результаты теста, без assert]

ниже привожу скрин с кнопкой которую хочу тыкнуть

[image: кнопка которую хочу нажать]

Comment: Этой информации недостаточно, чтоб дать корректный ответ, создайте минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду, я постарался расписать проблему, прикрепил код, описал действие которое ожидаю получить, и описал, что происходит на самом деле.
Не могли бы вы уточнить, что я мог бы сюда добавить, что бы мой вопрос был более наглядным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данную проблему поставив тайм слип перед кликом на кнопку, то есть теперь мой код выглядит так:

```
    def login_account(self, valid_user):
        self.click_button_account()
        self.click_on_button_u_menya_est_parol()
        self.enter_email(valid_user.email)
        self.enter_password(valid_user.password)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.click_btn_enter()
        time.sleep(10)
```

Так же поступали советы про какой то экшон чейн, если что то про это знаете то можете рассказать